# How to view multiple slides from same Powerpoint presentation simultaneously?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to be able to do:

- View two slides from same PowerPoint presentation simultaneously
- Edit these slides

My current workflow is to just make the far left "Slides" pane large enough I can see the content for the non-active slide and then jump back and forth as needed. This is somewhat annoying, though, because small text is not readable as you can only make this pane so large.

It would be great to not have to do this, but rather be able to more easily edit/view them simultaneously.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar - specifically, these slides are meant to be used to make a booklet of some kind... Any success with this?

Answer (score 11):

There is a "View" tab, and then there is a "New Window" button. Just click it and place the two windows side by side.

Comment: Maybe you could add that the `New Window` button automatically creates a second instance of the already opened PowerPoint file

Comment: But this is not in the same window. Isn't there any way to see more than a slide in a MS Powerpoint window? When you zoom out, it is very useful to see other slides in a continuous manner.

Comment: There's no such button in PowerPoint for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

In Powerpoint for Mac, open the top menu named "Window" (the menu, not the ribbon), and select "New Window".

Answer (score -1):

I found a much better solution for Mac users:

1. In PowerPoint click the print button and go to print preview screen.
2. Go to layout and select 6 pages per sheet etc.. if you want to view
       6 slides.
3. Click the pdf button on bottom left and just save it as a
       PDF.

Comment: I think the other Mac solution is better because it allows copying objects between slides easily.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is very simple and easy.

Open your PowerPoint file.
Open your other Powerpoint file.

Now you only see the last one. Correct?

OK, go to view and click on Cascade.

Now you see both. Correct?

Adjust the files so you see them parallel next to each other>

Advice: stretch your page to the full screen so you can enlarge your text for better view.

Comment: You haven't mentioned *how* to open the second file. Since it is the same file as already open, a simple double-click doesn't work